# Do recent c# compilers eliminate unnecessary array lookups?

Tags: c#

Assuming:

- A recent mono or other c# compiler is being used
- The code is performance sensitive

Motivation:

- to remove variable *vert*
- to improve readability
- to rely on compiler to cache array lookup

Example:

```
public static List<Vector2> Wavefronts(Vertex[] vertices, float s) {
    var result = new List<Vector2>(vertices.Length);
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++) {
        var vert = vertices[i];
        result[i] = vert.o + vert.v * s;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Surely if `vert` were removed and you were left with `result[i] = vertices[i].o + vertices[i].v * s;` then there would need to be *two* array bounds checks?

Comment: In any case, you could look at the disassembly (or use a tool like ILSpy to look at the IL which is emitted by the compiler)

Comment: If you want the array lookup to only happen once what is wrong with your current code? Sure, the compiler may be clever and cache the `vertices[i]` lookup for you but the best way to make sure it does is to do it yourself. Is there really a performance issue surrounding the use of your code as is? Also as I understand it your actual objective is to find the best performing code. In which case try out any variations you can think of and benchmark them properly and choose whichever performs best.

Comment: @WaiHaLee yes, that's probably the way to go, I'm just not that familiar with IL code and related tools

Comment: Also, it would be nice to know in general when such optimizations will happen.

Comment: I would expect any optimization of this to be a JIT concern, not a C# compiler one. It's e.g. responsible for eliminating array bounds checks, as an example.

Answer (score 1):

We should probably check the IL created by the .NET Standard 2.0 compiler in Release configuration. I'm not an IL expert myself, but let's just compare looking up twice and once in C# code and use dnSpy's automatic comments.

At first, your sample *already* does only one array lookup, and you store that vertex in the variable `vert`. This will create the following IL output; note there is only one `ldelem` instruction, meaning only one array lookup, as expected:

```
// loop start (head: IL_0037)
    IL_000D: ldarg.0    // Loads the argument at index 0 onto the evaluation stack.
    IL_000E: ldloc.1    // Loads the local variable at index 1 onto the evaluation stack.
    IL_000F: ldelem    ClassLibrary1.Vertex // Loads the element at a specified array index onto the top of the evaluation stack as the type specified in the instruction. 
    IL_0014: stloc.2    // Pops the current value from the top of the evaluation stack and stores it in a the local variable list at index 2.
    IL_0015: ldloc.0    // Loads the local variable at index 0 onto the evaluation stack.
    IL_0016: ldloc.1    // Loads the local variable at index 1 onto the evaluation stack.
    IL_0017: ldloc.2    // Loads the local variable at index 2 onto the evaluation stack.
    IL_0018: ldfld     class [Syroot.Maths]Syroot.Maths.Vector2 ClassLibrary1.Vertex::o // Finds the value of a field in the object whose reference is currently on the evaluation stack.
    IL_001D: ldloc.2    // Loads the local variable at index 2 onto the evaluation stack.
    IL_001E: ldfld     class [Syroot.Maths]Syroot.Maths.Vector2 ClassLibrary1.Vertex::v // Finds the value of a field in the object whose reference is currently on the evaluation stack.
    IL_0023: ldarg.1    // Loads the argument at index 1 onto the evaluation stack.
    IL_0024: call      class [Syroot.Maths]Syroot.Maths.Vector2 [Syroot.Maths]Syroot.Maths.Vector2::op_Multiply(class [Syroot.Maths]Syroot.Maths.Vector2, float32)  // Calls the method indicated by the passed method descriptor.
    IL_0029: call      class [Syroot.Maths]Syroot.Maths.Vector2 [Syroot.Maths]Syroot.Maths.Vector2::op_Addition(class [Syroot.Maths]Syroot.Maths.Vector2, class [Syroot.Maths]Syroot.Maths.Vector2) // Calls the method indicated by the passed method descriptor.
    IL_002E: callvirt  instance void class [netstandard]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<class [Syroot.Maths]Syroot.Maths.Vector2>::set_Item(int32, !0)    // Calls a late-bound method on an object, pushing the return value onto the evaluation stack.
    IL_0033: ldloc.1    // Loads the local variable at index 1 onto the evaluation stack.
    IL_0034: ldc.i4.1   // Pushes the integer value of 1 onto the evaluation stack as an int32.
    IL_0035: add    // Adds two values and pushes the result onto the evaluation stack.
    IL_0036: stloc.1    // Pops the current value from the top of the evaluation stack and stores it in a the local variable list at index 1.

    IL_0037: ldloc.1    // Loads the local variable at index 1 onto the evaluation stack.
    IL_0038: ldarg.0    // Loads the argument at index 0 onto the evaluation stack.
    IL_0039: ldlen  // Pushes the number of elements of a zero-based, one-dimensional array onto the evaluation stack.
    IL_003A: conv.i4    // Converts the value on top of the evaluation stack to int32.
    IL_003B: blt.s     IL_000D  // Transfers control to a target instruction (short form) if the first value is less than the second value.
// end loop
```

(I've also been using my `Syroot.Maths` library as I don't know what you're using, your code sample isn't complete.)

---

Now, *if* your sample would do more than one array lookup, aka:

```
public static List<Vector2> Wavefronts(Vertex[] vertices, float s)
{
    var result = new List<Vector2>(vertices.Length);
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
    {
        result[i] = vertices[i].o + vertices[i].v * s;
    }
    return result;
}
```

...a test compilation does *not* optimize it for me, it will do two array lookups (note the two `ldelema`):

```
// loop start (head: IL_003B)
    IL_000D: ldloc.0    // Loads the local variable at index 0 onto the evaluation stack.
    IL_000E: ldloc.1    // Loads the local variable at index 1 onto the evaluation stack.
    IL_000F: ldarg.0    // Loads the argument at index 0 onto the evaluation stack.
    IL_0010: ldloc.1    // Loads the local variable at index 1 onto the evaluation stack.
    IL_0011: ldelema   ClassLibrary1.Vertex // Loads the address of the array element at a specified array index onto the top of the evaluation stack as type & (managed pointer).
    IL_0016: ldfld     class [Syroot.Maths]Syroot.Maths.Vector2 ClassLibrary1.Vertex::o // Finds the value of a field in the object whose reference is currently on the evaluation stack.
    IL_001B: ldarg.0    // Loads the argument at index 0 onto the evaluation stack.
    IL_001C: ldloc.1    // Loads the local variable at index 1 onto the evaluation stack.
    IL_001D: ldelema   ClassLibrary1.Vertex // Loads the address of the array element at a specified array index onto the top of the evaluation stack as type & (managed pointer).
    IL_0022: ldfld     class [Syroot.Maths]Syroot.Maths.Vector2 ClassLibrary1.Vertex::v // Finds the value of a field in the object whose reference is currently on the evaluation stack.
    IL_0027: ldarg.1    // Loads the argument at index 1 onto the evaluation stack.
    IL_0028: call      class [Syroot.Maths]Syroot.Maths.Vector2 [Syroot.Maths]Syroot.Maths.Vector2::op_Multiply(class [Syroot.Maths]Syroot.Maths.Vector2, float32)  // Calls the method indicated by the passed method descriptor.
    IL_002D: call      class [Syroot.Maths]Syroot.Maths.Vector2 [Syroot.Maths]Syroot.Maths.Vector2::op_Addition(class [Syroot.Maths]Syroot.Maths.Vector2, class [Syroot.Maths]Syroot.Maths.Vector2) // Calls the method indicated by the passed method descriptor.
    IL_0032: callvirt  instance void class [netstandard]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<class [Syroot.Maths]Syroot.Maths.Vector2>::set_Item(int32, !0)    // Calls a late-bound method on an object, pushing the return value onto the evaluation stack.
    IL_0037: ldloc.1    // Loads the local variable at index 1 onto the evaluation stack.
    IL_0038: ldc.i4.1   // Pushes the integer value of 1 onto the evaluation stack as an int32.
    IL_0039: add    // Adds two values and pushes the result onto the evaluation stack.
    IL_003A: stloc.1    // Pops the current value from the top of the evaluation stack and stores it in a the local variable list at index 1.

    IL_003B: ldloc.1    // Loads the local variable at index 1 onto the evaluation stack.
    IL_003C: ldarg.0    // Loads the argument at index 0 onto the evaluation stack.
    IL_003D: ldlen  // Pushes the number of elements of a zero-based, one-dimensional array onto the evaluation stack.
    IL_003E: conv.i4    // Converts the value on top of the evaluation stack to int32.
    IL_003F: blt.s     IL_000D  // Transfers control to a target instruction (short form) if the first value is less than the second value.
// end loop
```

Why this is the case is beyond my knowledge. Maybe some compiler expert can clarify. And maybe this is still optimized by JIT, s. Damien's comment (another topic I'm not an expert in :-) ).

Comment: `ldelema` wouldn't be being used for a non-array with any possibility of an index operator. As I've said below the question I'd expect any optimizations here to be a JIT concern. E.g. the second code sample may be subject to common subexpression elimination.

Comment: I'm also interested in what happens in aot compilations (when there is no jit compilation).